# Angular2 ngSwitch with <template> only

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I would like to use ngSwitch to conditionally render some content, but I want that content to be the only thing to be rendered to the DOM. I'll illustrate with an example.

This is what I have currently:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="thing.name">
    <template ngSwitchWhen="foo">
        <div>FOOOOOO</div>
    </template>
    <template ngSwitchWhen="bar">
        <div>BARRRR</div>
    </template>
    <template ngSwitchWhen="cat">
        <div>CAT</div>
    </template>¯
    <template ngSwitchWhen="dog">
        <div>DOG</div>
    </template>
</div>
```

I'd like to change the parent element from a `<div>` to a `<template>` so only the most inner elements are actually inserted into the DOM. I suspect it is probably possible, because I know you can do something like that with `ngFor`, i.e.:

```html
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="things" let-thing="$implicit">
```

However, I haven't been able to work out how I could get it to work on an `ngSwitch`

Comment: This is documented in angular2 docs here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expanding-ngswitch-

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Edit: This answer is outdated. See @mrodri's answer for the new syntax

That is now supported since the final release. The following code can be applied to your example :

```
<div *ngSwitch="thing.name">
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="foo">
        <div>FOOOOOO</div>
    </template>
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="bar">
        <div>BARRRR</div>
    </template>
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="cat">
        <div>CAT</div>
    </template>¯
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="dog">
        <div>DOG</div>
    </template>
</div>
```

See [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template) for more info

Comment: [ngSwitchCase]="cat" will look for a varible named `cat`

Comment: use `ng-template` or `ng-container` instead of `template`. [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ng-container)

Comment: @Gabriel - `code`<div [ngSwitch] = "thing.name">
                    <p *ngSwitchCase="'red'">para Red</p>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="foo">FOOOOOO</div>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="bar">BARRRR</div>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="cat">CAT</div>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="dog">DOG</div>
                    <p *ngSwitchDefault>universe..</p>
                </div>

Comment: Should be *ngSwitchCase="condition" rather than [ngSwitchCase]="condition"

Answer (score 40):

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="activeLayout">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'layout1'" [ngTemplateOutlet]="template1"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault [ngTemplateOutlet]="defaultTemplate"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

This is my solution when I need to make a switch of different ng-template.
I hope it works for you.

Comment: <ng-container [ngSwitch]="activeLayout">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'layout1'" [ngTemplateOutlet]="template1"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault [ngTemplateOutlet]="defaultTemplate"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

Comment: If you put three backticks on either side of the code it'll format properly - see my edit.

Answer (score 14):

As of Angular 6 `ng-template` or `template` don't work - use `ng-container`

```
<div [ngSwitch]="'case 3'">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'case 1'">
      <li > Case 1</li>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'case 2'">
      <li > Case 2</li>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'case 3'">
      <li > Case 3</li>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to remove the enclosing tag, you can use ng-container instead of div. Then up to you to provide whatever you want inside the switch case (here below 'divs'). Thanks to @Stephane Leger for the trick

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="thing.name">
    <div [ngSwitchCase]="'foo'">
        Inner content 1
    </div>
    <div [ngSwitchCase]="'bar'">
        Inner content 2
    </div>
    <div [ngSwitchCase]="'cat'">
        Inner content 3
    </div>
    <div [ngSwitchCase]="'dog'">
        Inner content 4
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not supported. See this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3306

From this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3306#issuecomment-125368361

> This works as intended. I know it is a bit strange. But if we change
>   it to
>
> ```
> <ul *ng-switch="value">   
>   <li *ng-switch-when="'1'">is 1</li>   
>   <li *ng-switch-when="'2'">is 2</li>   
>   <li *ng-switch-default>is another value</li> 
> </ul>
> ```
>
> What it would say is that `<ul>` should not be created until
>   `ng-switch` decides it needs to be created. That means that the nested
>   `ng-switch-when` would never be created. If `ng-switch` would somehow
>   skip itself, it would remove `<ul>` which would change the user
>   behavior. So there is no simple way to create nesting.
>
> Think of `ng-switch` as a container. It always is there, and think of
>   `ng-switch-when` as templates which may or net may be there. The
>   container can not be removed, and hence can not have `*`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will look for another solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div [ngSwitch] = "thing.name">
                <p *ngSwitchCase="'red'">para Red</p>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="foo">FOOOOOO</div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="bar">BARRRR</div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="cat">CAT</div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="dog">DOG</div>
                <p *ngSwitchDefault>universe..</p>
            </div>
```